# Problem testing method returning List of custom objects

Tags: apex, method

My company is using custom objects for Pricelist, Pricelist Items, and Products.

I'm having this error trying to test my method to get a return of the Pricelist object as a List of Id.

Line: 11, Column: 5 - 
*"Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: List IPriceDecorator.getPriceList(Id, Set)"*

```
global class IPriceDecorator {

    global static List<Pricelist__c> getPriceList(Id priceListId, Set<Id> setProdId) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '__ [cls IPriceDecorator - getPriceList] - Start...');
        //System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '__ [cls IPriceDecorator - getPriceList] - priceListId: ' + priceListId);
        //System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '__ [cls IPriceDecorator - getPriceList] - setProdId: ' + setProdId);

        List<Pricelist__c> priceList = [ SELECT Id 
                                        , Name
                                        , IsActive__c
                                        FROM Pricelist__c
                                        WHERE Id =: setProdId ];

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '__ [cls IPriceDecorator - getPriceList] - priceList: ' + priceList);

        return priceList.isEmpty() ? null : priceList;       

    }

}
```

I'm running this snippet in Execute Anonymous.

```
String Id_Field = 'Id'; Id priceListId = 'a1t0O000005OsARQA0';
List<Product__c> prodList = [SELECT Id FROM Product__c];
System.debug('prodList: ' + prodList);

Set<Id> setProdId = new Set<Id>(); setProdId =
CollectionUtils.createSet(prodList, Id_Field);

System.debug('setProdId: ' + setProdId); IPriceDecorator obj = new
IPriceDecorator(); obj.getPriceList(priceListId, setProdId);
```

I really don't understand why this error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

The `getPriceList` method is static. It is associated with the class `IPriceDecorator`, not an instance of the class.

You should call it like this:

```
IPriceDecorator.getPriceList(priceListId, setProdId)
```

You can read more about static methods in Apex here: [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)